# Axios (JS) devuelve datos sesgados y no puedo recuperarlos correctamente.-

Tags: vue.js, axios

Estoy realizando un proyecto con VUE + Axios en el que intento recuperar un resultado en formato JSON, pero al abrir el response.data algunos de los values tienen son undefined.

Probé modificando la respuesta para obtener un String y todo parece correcto:

```
getConexion(id) {
    const url = `${url}`
    return axios.get(url, {
        transformResponse: [function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }],
        responseType: 'text'
    })
}
```

El String que estoy recibiendo sería

```
"[{"id_conexion":1,"plazoDispuesto":100,"radioDispuesto":100,"fechaDeInicio":1569283200000,"fechaDeFin":1584748800000,"editable":false,"caso":"32165487","firmasDeUsuario":[]}"
```

Pero al utilizar JSON.parse() el resultado me devuelve:

```
{
    editable: undefined,
    fechaDeFin: undefined,
    fechaDeInicio: undefined,
    firmasDeUsuario: Array [],
    id_conexion: 1,
    plazoDispuesto: 100,
    radioDispuesto: 100,
    caso: "32165487"
}
```

Para la consulta estoy utilizando [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), he probado recibiendo en formato String, como JSON pero el resultado es el mismo.
Desde ya agradezco sus respuetas.-

Edito: El servido Rest está construido en JAVA con Spring Boot.

---

Sigo sin entender lo que sucede.
Cuando ejecuto la petición la respuesta es correcta:

```
apiService.getConexionesByIdCAso(idCaso).then(
    function(res) {
        if (res.data) {
           console.log(res.data);
                ...
```

Resultado:

```
[{
   editable: false,
   fechaDeFin: 1569334887087
   fechaDeInicio: 1569334887087,
   firmasDeUsuario: Array [],
   id_conexion: 1,
   plazoDispuesto: 100,
   radioDispuesto: 100,
   caso: "32165487"
 }]
```

El resultado es correcto hasta acá, el JSON está completo, pero si desarrollo el método, por ejemplo recorriéndolo,  se rompe el resultado.

```
apiService.getConexionesByIdCAso(idCaso).then(
    function(res) {
        if (res.data) {
            console.log(res.data[0]);...
                //Al poner[0] algunos valores pasan a ser undefined y otros no
```

Resultado:

```
{
 editable: undefined,
 fechaDeFin: undefined
 fechaDeInicio: undefined,
 firmasDeUsuario: Array [],
 id_conexion: 1,
 plazoDispuesto: 100,
 radioDispuesto: 100,
 caso: "32165487"
}
```

Comment: Saludos bro, bienvenido a SOes, ¿has probado usar POSTman como herramienta de debugging?

Comment: Hola. En realidad con Postman la respuesta es correcta. El problema solo me lo da en el navegador. Tanto en Firefox como en Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
getConexion(id) {
    const url = `${url}`
    return axios.get(url)
                .then(function(response) {
                       console.log(response.data);                           
                       return response.data;           
                     });
}
```

Comment: console.log(response.data);

Comment: jooo, verdad xD! *actualizando, gracias hermano

Comment: Cuando hago el console.log(response.data) me devuelve el JSON tal cual arriba, con varios valores 'undefined'. El asunto es que si modifico la petición agregando `responseType:'text'` el contenido en String está completo. `"[{"id_conexion":1,"plazoDispuesto":100,"radioDispuesto":100,"fechaDeInicio":1569283200000,"fechaDeFin":1584748800000,"editable":false,"caso":"32165487","firmasDeUsuario":[]}]"`

Comment: En ese caso el problema está en el backend. Edita la pregunta agregando el código que usas.

Comment: El backend es Java + Spring Boot. El método sería:
`@Override
public List<Conexion> getAllCasoData(String caso) {

 List<Conexion> conexiones = getSession()
    .createQuery("select c from Conexion c "
+ "join c.caso cc"
+ "where cc.id_caso = :id)")
    .setParameter("id", id).list();
return conexiones;
`

Comment: _Update_:
Cuando hago el **console.log(res.data)** todo es correcto, pero una vez que me pongo a recorrer el array, los datos pasan a ser _undefined_
Javascript
`apiService
        .getConexionesByIdCAso(idCaso)
        .then(
          function(res) {
            if (res.data) {
              console.log(res.data);...`
El resultado es correcto hasta acá, pero si desarrollo el método se rompe el resultado.
Javascript
`apiService
        .getConexionesByIdCAso(idCaso)
        .then(
          function(res) {
            if (res.data) {
              console.log(res.data[0]);...`

Answer (score 0):

Al final di con el error: Cuando ejecuto la petición la respuesta es correcta:

```
apiService.getConexionesByIdCAso(idCaso).then(
    function(res) {
        if (res.data) {
           console.log(res.data);
                ...
```

Resultado:

```
[{
   editable: false,
   fechaDeFin: 1569334887087
   fechaDeInicio: 1569334887087,
   firmasDeUsuario: Array [],
   id_conexion: 1,
   plazoDispuesto: 100,
   radioDispuesto: 100,
   caso: "32165487"
 }]
```

El resultado es correcto hasta acá, el JSON está completo, pero si desarrollo el método, por ejemplo recorriéndolo, se rompe el resultado. ¿Por qué? Más adelante realicé un cambio en el valor de la variable, y por algún motivo el console.log() que se ejecutó "antes" me trae el valor del cambio que hice al final. No sé por qué motivo el console.log() me devuelve el resultado de lo que se ejecutará después, pero al final encontré que el error no estaba en la respuesta del servidor, o los pasos que seguí para procesar el JSON, sino que se trataba de una falla en otro método que trabajaba con los datos ya asignados a sus respectivos objetos.

Ejemplo:

```
apiService.getConexionesByIdCAso(idCaso).then(
    function(res) {
        if (res.data) {
            console.log(res.data[0]);...
            res.data[0].editable = undefined;
```

Resultado:

```
{
 editable: undefined,
 fechaDeFin: undefined
 fechaDeInicio: undefined,
 firmasDeUsuario: Array [],
 id_conexion: 1,
 plazoDispuesto: 100,
 radioDispuesto: 100,
 caso: "32165487"
}
```